# Android ListView scrolling programmatically with CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I need to scroll programmatically a ListView that is using a custom CursorAdapter.

The problem is that the unique way to scroll in code the ListView is using the method **setSelectiomFromTop**, but calling this method cause **bindView** for ALL items of the ListView. I'm calling setSelectionFromTop inside a scroll listener of another view so i'm getting a lot of GC for this continuous rebinding of the listview.

There is another way to do this without rebinding all items of the ListView continuously?

Answer (score 0):

Try `list.scrollBy(x, y)` or `list.scrollTo(x, y)`.

Comment: i have already tried those methods... the result is that only the container will scroll without showing listview childs